# What does the 'suppressed' folder mean on the NCBI ftp genomes website?

Tags: phylogenetics, webservice

I wish to understand the term `suppressed` in folder nomenclature on the NCBI ftp genomes website?

Example: [here](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/refseq/bacteria/Oscillatoriales_cyanobacterium_C42_A2020_001/all_assembly_versions/) ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/refseq/bacteria/Oscillatoriales_cyanobacterium_C42_A2020_001/all_assembly_versions/

Normally, I'd see folders with names like `representative` or `latest assembly`, which are pretty straightforward. But what does `suppressed` refer to in this case?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/refseq/about/prokaryotes/reannotation/) you have the explanation:

> Suppressed genomes: Several hundred RefSeq bacterial genomes that did
> not pass assembly or annotation quality validation have been
> suppressed(RefSeq genome quality criteria). An FTP report file listing
> the most recent suppressions will be provided soon in the RefSeq FTP
> site.